# Show $f(x) := x|x|$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Indeed this challenges my intuition of how different functions (that are not necessarily differentiable) interact to become differentiable which is nice.

I wonder if my proof suffices to show that it is indeed differentiable at $x = 0$.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x|x| - 0}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{|x|}{1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0} |x| = 0$$

The existence of that limit by definition shows differentiability right?

Comment: In addition the function $|x|$ is not differentiable because when expanding the definition of differentiability and the absolute value, we get an inconsistency. So I have to think that somehow the function $x$ kinda crushes |x| or something like that right?

Comment: Your proof is correct. "somehow the function $x$ kinda crushes $|x|$", exactly, $|x|$ is not differentiable because when going from the right or from the left the "behavior" is different, but when multiplying by $x$ both sides behavior "collapse" to $0$,  and because $0=-0$ the difference in the behavior does not exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct and very elegant indeed.

You have said that it is anti-intuitive for this function to be differentiabe  at $x=0$, but if you look at the graph of this function you notice that it is very smooth at $x=0$, so it is not surprising for the function to be differentiabe at $x=0$

However there is something very interesting about it. It is about the Wronskian of $x|x|$ and $x^2$.

The wronskian of these two function is identically zero over the entire real line but the functions are linearly independent over the real line.

Answer (score 2):

Notice

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{ f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{ x \cdot (-x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} - x = 0 $$

and

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ x \cdot (+x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}  x = 0 $$

Hence,

$$ f'(0) = 0 $$

Notice that

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 , \; \;\; x \geq 0 \\ -x^2 , \; \; \; x <0 \end{cases} $$